# Why my website doesn't appear in Google search results?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, google-search

I've made a simple website for a friend's bakery and it doesn't appear in Google's search results **even if I search for the whole domain name** of the site.

What can be the problem?

How to make it appear?

[(The site)](http://www.pekseg-aquincum.hu)

Comment: Since when is the site up? You need to give it a few weeks from the time site is up until Google indexes it.

Comment: I see. About 3 weeks.

Comment: Do you have google analytics? That will speed up the proccess. You got good internal linking, backlinks, sitemap, etc?

Comment: @Martijn checking the link it's a one-page website. No sitemap, no analytics. The only links there are are on same page (#link) and he also has a google maps iframe.

Comment: That's right...

Answer (score 0):

To detect any possible problems it would be wise to setup Google Webmaster tools for the domain. You can make an account here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Once activated for the website, it will report you any errors (if any) that google crawler might receive when indexing your site. It also allows you to submit a sitemap for your site, so I would generate that and for your website and submit it.

Webmaster tools also allow you to see your website from google crawler's point of view, so you can use that to check if there might be any problems.

Once your Webmaster tools are setup for the domain, give it some again, it will report any errors that crawler is seeing once it comes to index your site again.